# Linear model with partially time-varying coefficients

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, asymptotics, kernel-smoothing

Suppose we have a linear model with time-varying coefficients
$$
y_i = x_i' \beta_{t_i} + \epsilon_i, \; i = 1, 2, \cdots, n
$$
where the design points are $t_i = \frac{i}{n}$, and $\beta(t): [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is a component-wise Lipshitz function on $[0,1]$.

A standard way to estimate $\beta$ is by local kernel regression of Nadaraya-Watson type, a simplified version of which goes as follows (see, for example, [Cai (2007) Journal of Econometrics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407605002058?casa_token=qMilFSkyOzoAAAAA:WyOkJQOX2K4jYsJ4Fc3I82_4pNZYmduaMiSqIIRSAvxFFghylYaGGPZ0tCF8GDHIEGNg-gf020A)).

Let $K(s)$ be a symmetric continuous kernel function and $K_{h, t} (s) = \frac{1}{h} K(\frac{s-t}{h})$.
Local kernel regression means that, at a given $t \in [0,1]$, one estimates $\beta(t)$ by fitting the  working linear model
$$
K_{h, t} (t_i) y_i = K_{h, t} (t_i) x_i' \beta(t) + u_i, \; i = 1, 2, \cdots, n. \quad(*)
$$

With weakly dependent data $(x_i, y_i)$, for a given bandwidth $h$ it can be shown that
$$
\hat{\beta}(t) - \beta(t) = O_p(h) + O_p(\frac{1}{\sqrt{nh}}),
$$
a "bias + variance" type of expression.
Therefore the optimal bandwidth is $O(n^{-\frac13})$ and with this optimal bandwidth selection,
$\hat{\beta}(t)$ converges to $\beta(t)$ at $n^{\frac13}$-rate pointwise and in $L^2[0,1]$.
([Cai (2007)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407605002058?casa_token=qMilFSkyOzoAAAAA:WyOkJQOX2K4jYsJ4Fc3I82_4pNZYmduaMiSqIIRSAvxFFghylYaGGPZ0tCF8GDHIEGNg-gf020A) obtained $n^{\frac25}$-rate under the assumption that $\beta$ is twice-differentiable.)

### Question

Suppose some of the components of $\beta$ are time-invariant, say
$\beta = (\beta_1', \beta_2'(t))'$ and $\beta_1$ is a constant vector of parameters.

Now I am going to make the following proposition, which is fairly naive and whose conclusion must be wrong.

Since $\beta_1$ is time-invariant, it can be estimated consistently by fitting the working model $(*)$ at multiple points, say
$m$ points, then average the $m$ resulting estimates. If $m$ is constant,
the resulting averaged estimate would have variance reduced by factor of $\frac{1}{m^2}$ but rate of convergence to
true parameter is still $n^{\frac13}$.

Now let $m$ grow with $n$, say $m = n^{\alpha}$, then the resulting rate is $n^{ 2 \alpha + \frac13 }$.
In particular, if $\alpha > \frac{1}{12}$, then the resulting rate is faster than $n^{\frac12}$.

However, *this cannot be right*, as $n^{\frac12}$ is the optimal parametric rate (there is no unit-root data involved).
(The parametric $n^{\frac12}$ -rate has been obtained for the time-invariant parameters in this setting by [Zhang and Wu (2012) Annals of Statistics](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1344610587), under more restrictive conditions.)

What's wrong with the above argument, and what would be the correct rate from the above procedure?

(One possible reason is joint vs. separate convergence---one must choose $h$ and $m$ simultaneously, not take the limit in $h$ and then $m$.
This is not very precise. Further clarification would be nice.)